# Change the function name of an event in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I want to change the function associated to an event dynamically. I tried this:

```
(click) = "{{myFunction}}"
```

But I get an error "Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected".
I need to change in TypeScript myFunction to one or other function upon conditions.

Comment: That is not gonna work. How can you know the different methods name in component? You will have to extract all methods name and find out which is to bind. That means you need to change your template accordingly.

Comment: If the user clicks the button something happens in the screen but I need to disable the button functionality for just a few seconds before allowing the user to execute the same function to avoid errors. So after the user clicks I change the function name to whatever for a few seconds and after that I restore it back to normal

Comment: Replacing event name cannot be achieved and supported in Angular. You can bind a boolean to [disabled] to control the availability.

Comment: I wanted to correct my previous comment but it won't allow me. It's not a button it's an image, and "[disabled]" is not a property of images.

Comment: how do you want to interact with the image? hide or something else? let me know. I can do some mock up in plunker.

Comment: just clicking the image fires the function. Then any interactivity with the image must be disabled in order to prevent errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a plunker for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/se3kz5AF4sSmgHue8W7u?p=preview

```
onImgClick() {
    if(this.imgDisabled){
      console.log('img disabled');
      return;
    }
    alert('clicked');
    this.imgDisabled = true;
    console.log('img disabled');
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      that.imgDisabled = false;
      console.log('img enabled');
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `that`?

Comment: this in () => { this. } will be the reference of the function. You need to use that to access component.

Comment: You need to bone up on arrow functions. `this` in `() => { this. }` will **not** be the "reference of the function". it will be the `this` from `onImgClick`, which is the object of which it is a part. That concept is basic to arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
(click)="myFunction()"

class MyComponent {
  myFunction = this.click;

  click() { 
    console.log("clicked");
    this.myFunction = () => { };
    setTimeout(() => this.myFunction = this.click, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works and is very short. I believe I saw this pattern somewhere else, does it have a name?

Answer (score 0):

The technical term for what you are trying to do is "throttling". Try searching for that. Many libraries will provide that functionality in some form. Most often, it's implemented as a "higher-order function": a function which takes an underlying function and returns a throttled version of it. The basic logic is:

```
function throttle(fn, ms) {
  let last = 0;

  return function() {
    const now = +new Date();

    if (now > last + ms) {
      last = now;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}
```

Now in your component:

```
(click)="myFunction()"

myFunction = throttle(this.click);
```